# how to collect environment containing verbatim text and definitions with parameters to typset it later?

Tags: verbatim, tokenization

I'm stuck trying to collect tex tokens (detokenized) and output them latter with `\scantokens`.
Problem is that can't drop duplicated parameters (`#`)
Ideally would be great to read all the content as a string until some marker but this probably requires to read tokens one by one and change their catcodes to string and add spaces in certain places.

For example I want to collect `thebibliography` and output it at the end of document. Problem raises
when I uncomment `\def\path...`. It will give an error `! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\def\printOrigBibliography{%
    \let\thebibliography\copythebibliography
    \let\endthebibliography\copyendthebibliography   
    %% fix of space after \verb token
    \let\origverb\verb
    \def\verb##1{\origverb##1}%
    \expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\my@envthebibliography\noexpand}\relax
    }

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \environbodyname\envthebibliography
    \let\copythebibliography\thebibliography
    \let\copyendthebibliography\endthebibliography    
    \RenewEnviron{thebibliography}
      {\xdef\my@envthebibliography{%
        \noexpand\begin{thebibliography}%
        \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\envthebibliography}%
        \noexpand\end{thebibliography}}%
      }%
    }
    
\AtEndDocument{\printOrigBibliography}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
%\def\path#1{#1}

\bibitem{R}
aa \verb|a_a| bb

\end{thebibliography}

Final words 
\end{document}    \end{document}
```

Can I drop some how duplicated parameters down by one level?
I tried to drop it with:

```
\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{%
   \expandafter\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\fooo
       \expandafter{\my@envthebibliography}\noexpand}\relax
\fooo
```

but then I have `\verb` problems again.

Comment: no, I can't control the bibliography input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't storing the bibliography in a box simpler?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\let\origthebibliography\thebibliography
\let\origendthebibliography\endthebibliography
\newsavebox{\bibliographybox}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}
 {\global\setbox\bibliographybox=\vtop\bgroup\origthebibliography}
 {\origendthebibliography\egroup}
\AtEndDocument{\unvbox\bibliographybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\def\path#1{#1}

\bibitem{R}
aa \verb|a_a| bb

\end{thebibliography}

Final words \cite{R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\unvbox` will also allow it to break across page boundaries, is that correct?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes: the command removes one level of boxing

Comment: ...in an unexpandable way.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's irrelevant for the problem at hand. Apparently, the OP gets some autogenerated code with the bibliography at the beginning and wants to print it at the end.

Comment: No slight intended...I was mostly reminding my own feeble brain on how `\unvbox` works.

Comment: Enrico that is a good point to solve my example. I'll wait for a while maybe someone will give a hint how to store tex content as string that I could later manipulate with this content.